Worldpay payment gateway integration, redirect after success transaction
I am having an issue redirecting the user back to the mobile app after doing the payment transaction on the mobile browser. What is the easiest way to redirect the user back to the mobile app if the payment succeeds. I tried to send the returnUrl as mentioned in the documentations but it did not work.
